# Can mars have solar panals

Tags: mars

Can ***Mars*** have ***Solar Panels***?
    I need to know

Please

Comment: What do you mean? Mars is a planet. You can put solar panels on Mars to power things, but the planet itself doesn't need solar panels. It's a planet.

Comment: You probably mean, "Can solar panels work at Mars?" Yes. They've been doing that for over two decades now, and the *Juno* spacecraft is using solar power all the way out at Jupiter.

Answer (score 4):

[Opportunity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_(rover)) and [Spirit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_(rover)) say yes.

Comment: [Sojurner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sojourner_(rover)) was there before and also says yes. The lander [Phoenix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_(spacecraft)) was also solar powered.